# Entity Framework excluding some properties

Tags: database, entity-framework, properties, entity, dbcontext

When I add new entities to the database I need to exclude some of their properties because I want to add it later by updating them.

How can I do it the clean way? For now to exclude some collection I'm doing this:

```
myModel.SomeList.Clear();
DbContext.MyModels.Add(myModel);
```

and later update the collection property, but that doesn't feel clean and I'd like to retain the collection in my code for later use, so I need something that would tell EF to not add it to the database.

Comment: Why do you have SomeList filled if the entity is new? Can you not fill it from beginning?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using code-first and EF version 5.0+ you can do this in the object mapping.

```
internal class BotConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<Bot>
{
    internal BotConfiguration()
    {
        this.ToTable("Bots", "Bot");
        this.HasEntitySetName("Bots");

        this.HasKey(t => t.Id);
        this.Property(t => t.Id);
        this.Ignore(t=> t.BotHeight);
```

In the example above, EF will ignore the BotHeight property on the Bot object